# show button after clicking another button in mysqli

Tags: php, button, mysqli

i have this code in index.php :

```
<?php require 'class.php';require_once './session.php';$conn = new db_class();$read = $conn->read();$data = [];while($fetch = $read->fetch_array()){ 
$data[] = $fetch;}?>
<table   class = "table table-bordered table-responsive ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Segment</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($data as $fetch): ?>
                <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
                    <td class="segment" contenteditable="true"><?= $fetch['segment'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button class = "btn btn-default action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" data-action="update"> 
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update
                        </button> 
                        | 

                        <button class = "btn btn-success action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" type="submit" data-action="activate">
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate
                        </button> 
                        | 
                        <button class = "btn btn-danger action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>"  data-action="deactivate">
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> deactivate
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this the function in class.php

```
  public function read()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id,segment FROM `segments`") or die($this->conn->error);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

all i want is to show if activation is disabled to show only activate button and if activation is on to show only the deactivate button,
i use 0 for deactivation and 1 for activation

Comment: how can you decide that button is activated or not. is there anything from db?

Comment: yes there is i have a table called segment wich have activation by defaut is 1 so i want to make only show the deactivate button and after clicking on it i want to show the activate button @Omi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to hide the deactivate button use `style` `display` to hide
button. Write click event on activate button then use jquery [hide/show](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) to hide activate button & show deactivate button.

```js
$(".activate-btn").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
$(".deactivate-btn").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table   class = "table table-bordered table-responsive ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Segment</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($data as $fetch): ?>
                <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
                    <td class="segment" contenteditable="true"><?= $fetch['segment'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button class = "btn btn-default action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" data-action="update"> 
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update
                        </button> 
                        | 

                        <button class = "btn btn-success activate-btn action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" type="submit" data-action="activate">
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate
                        </button> 
                        
                        <button style="display:none" class = "btn btn-danger deactivate-btn action-btn " data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>"  data-action="deactivate">
                            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> deactivate
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```